# List of objects in front of an object in PowerPoint using VSTO

Tags: powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-2013, powerpoint-2016

There are few shape objects in a PowerPoint slide. The rectangle, ellipse, parallelogram, triangle and pentagon were drawn in that order meaning rectangle is at the back of all objects.

When iterating through the objects in PowerPoint, **is it possible to get a list of all objects that lie in front/behind of an object and fall partially or fully within it**. There may be a lot of objects in the PowerPoint and comparing each object against each object is a not a favorable solution.

I would like to get the list of objects(in this case - ellipse, parallelogram and triangle) against the rectangle. How can I achieve that programmatically using VSTO?

[image: Source PowerPoint slide]

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint object model provides the [Shape.AutoShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.autoshapetype) property which  returns or sets the shape type for the specified Shape object, which must represent an `AutoShape` other than a line, freeform drawing, or connector. So, you may use something like that:

```
If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Type = msoAutoShape Then
  If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
    'Do something here
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks,I don't think this answers my query at all. I need those objects for that have non-zero intersection with the rectangle. If I have to compare every other object against the rectangle, it would be a solution; but not a good one.

Comment: You can use Shape's properties to find out and intersection with others.

Comment: " If I have to compare every other object against the rectangle, it would be a solution; but not a good one."  Perhaps not optimal, but it's the only way to do the job in PowerPoint.