# How to find out if two shape objects in PowerPoint intersect with each other?

Tags: powerpoint, office-addins, add-in, shapes, powerpoint-2016

There are multiple shapes present in a PowerPoint slide. See image below

[image]

As can be seen in the image, we have 3 shapes - rectangle, triangle and circle. I would like to iterate over the shapes in the slide and create a list of shapes for each shape with which it intersects. Shape intersection here refers to actual visual shape intersection and not the rectangular bounding box around those shapes.

List 1 - triangle, circle
List 2 - circle, rectangle
List 3 - rectangle, triangle

Is there any API to determine shape intersection? I have checked the PowerPoint add-in API, haven't found any. What approach should I follow?

Comment: Other than by comparing the bounding boxes, PPT offers no help for what you're after. I suspect the only solution will be math and trigonometry.

Comment: Ah, here's another thought: for each pair of shapes you want to test, use .MergeShapes (msoMergeIntersect)  If that produces a new shape, the shapes overlap. If no new shape, there was no overlap.  Keeping track of the z-order will be a nightmare if you try to do this on an existing slide. Instead, add a new blank slide to the presentation, then for each pair of shapes you want to compare, copy them to the blank slide, merge, test, delete the slide's .ShapeRange then move on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to determine the shape intersection. You need to use `Shape`'s properties to find out and intersection with others. A similar questions was posted some time ago, see [List of objects in front of an object in PowerPoint using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72683304/list-of-objects-in-front-of-an-object-in-powerpoint-using-vsto) for more information.